# python replace cols values in dataframe given a secondary df. # Check for duplicates KeyError:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

Given df1 and df2 dataframes, I would like to substitute the 'Name' items in df2 for their corresponding 'Area' values in df1.

In other words, the values in df2['Name] should be respectively A1 A3 A2 A1 A2

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'Albert', 'Josh'],
            'Area':['A1','A2','A3','A1']
                       })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Albert', 'Nick', 'Josh','Nick'],
            'pet':['dog','cat','mouse','dog','mouse']
                       })
```

After searching for some suggestions, I added this line:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['Area','Name'], how='left')
```

print(df)

But I get this error:

```
# Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Area'
```

and this line:

```
df = df2['Name'].map(df1.set_index('Area')['Name'])
print(df)
```

outputs this error

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: For first use `df = df2.merge(df1, on=['Name'], how='left')`

Comment: For second use `df2['Name'].map(df1.set_index('Name')['Area'])`

Answer (score 0):

That's because both dataframes should have a column named `Area`.

So remove the `Area` when merging.

```py
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['Name'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any column named `'Area'` in your second dataframe (`df2`). This is why the error is being shown.

Comment: unfortunately none of the solutions posted here work. By printing df I only get the 'Name' column filled in with NaN values

Comment: Could you please state your objective more clearly? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: As I wrote above, the objective is that the values df2['Name] should be respectively A1 A3 A2 A1 A2. That is because when df1['Name'] = 'Tom', df1['Area]='A1', when df1['Name'] = 'Nick', df1['Area']=A2' etc...  clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict and zip commands to make the 2 dataframe columns you want to map into a dictionary.  Then you can map the values easily.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'Albert', 'Josh'],
     'Area':['A1','A2','A3','A1']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':['Tom', 'Albert', 'Nick', 'Josh','Nick'],
    'pet':['dog','cat','mouse','dog','mouse']
})

df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].map(dict(zip(df1['Name'], df1['Area'])))
```

Comment: this code almost produces the right output. The new 3rd and 5th row are 'NaN' when they should both be 'A2'

Comment: That is because in df1, the name 'nick' isn't capitalized.  It is capitalized in df2.  Hope that solves it :)